# Next js config term 'next dev' is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

next : The term 'next' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Could you please explain what it is you're trying to do? And what the expected output is?

Comment: I assume you're trying to run an NPM script, and the correct command is `npm run dev`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.